# Twitter Bootstrap DropDown Menu Issue

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to Bootstrap and am learning how to use it. I'm having some trouble getting a simple Dropdown menu to "drop down" when clicked on [this](http://test.rfahaiti.org) beta site.

I would really appreciate if someone could look at my page source and let me know what's wrong. Below is the html of the dropdown menu.

```
 <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="brand" href="/">Restavec Freedom Alliance</a>
      <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="/blog">Blog</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li class="nav-header">Nav header</li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
```

The reason why your menu is not working properly is because you're initiating the same script three times. The `bootstrap.js` and `.min.js` variation have all the plugins packaged within them, one is the full dev version and the other is meant for production, the minified version. The third script is a loose plugin script which is not needed if you are already including the packed version. So remove the second and third scripts loaded in your header and your menu should work.

**Edit**

Just noticed something else, the `.collapse` class was also preventing the menu from showing since it is only used upon mobile nav collapse, so it does not need to be included.

Comment: Hi Andres, thanks so much for your quick answer! For some reason it's still no functioning properly. I removed the second and third scripts.

Comment: @PatrickNommensen remove the `.collapse` class from your menu's  `.nav-collapse` container, that class is added automatically when using the responsive sheet so it should not be there by default. `<div class="nav-collapse collapse">`

Comment: @PatrickNommensen glad i was of help. If the answer satisfied your question please approve it to close this thread. You can do so by ticking the gray checkmark next to the answer of your choice.